# Loading from web & cropping image

Tags: java, android, bitmap

Trying to load a image from a website and crop the center of that particular image into a circle. I currently am trying to us the below code. There are two things wrong with the code... One is I cannot use net functions in my main method. And two I am cropping it correctly?

```
private Drawable getAvatar(String link) {
    RoundedBitmapDrawable drw = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(link);
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
        drw = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(Resources.getSystem(), bmp);
        drw.setCornerRadius(Math.max(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight()) / 2.0f);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    return drw;
}
```

I think my options are to either make a new class that is a thread and load all images there... I need these images to be updated into another activity.

AsyncTask is causing skipping in frames I need a real thread but still need to update UI

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [async task](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to do processes in background which you are not supposed to be doing on main thread.

For cropping an image you can do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18378873/3530596). This example crops any image in circle.

Comment: @overload Async task causes it to skip frames I need a better method